# Inserting a PID in the Linux Hash-Table

Tags: linux, hash, process, kernel, pid

Currently I'm working on a Linux-Kernel-Module, that can hide any normal Process.
The hiding works fine, but I haven't found a way to unhide the process yet.
First I delete the **struct task_struct** from the big list of task_structs inside the Kernel:

```
struct task_struct *p;

//Finding the correct task_struct
for_each_process(p)
    if(p->pid == pid){

        // Removing the task_struct
        struct list_head *next = task->tasks.next;
        struct list_head *prev = task->tasks.prev;

        next->prev=prev;
        prev->next=next;
     }
```

But the task_struct is still traceable, because it's inside a hash_table containing every process' task_struct. In fact most of the PID-Lookup is performed by this hash-table. Removing the task-struct from there is a bit tricky:

```
struct pid *pid; //struct pid of the task_struct
//Deleting for every pid_namespace the pid_chain from the hash_list
for (i = 0; i <= pid->level; i++) {
    struct upid *upid = pid->numbers + i;
    hlist_del_rcu(&upid->pid_chain);
}
```

The Problem is to restore both structs: Inserting the task_struct back in the list of task_structs is easy, but I haven't found a way to restore the link in the hash-table. It's difficult, because the kernel doesn't expose the needed structures.

Inside the Kernel, it's done within this line:

```
hlist_add_head_rcu(&upid->pid_chain,&pid_hash[pid_hashfn(upid->nr, upid->ns)]);
```

**pid_hashfn** and **pid_hash** are defined as follows:

```
#define pid_hashfn(nr, ns)  hash_long((unsigned long)nr + (unsigned long)ns, pidhash_shift)

static struct hlist_head *pid_hash;
```

And the struct I need to insert, is the pid_chain:

```
struct hlist_node pid_chain;
```

**So my question is,** how can I insert the pid_chain in the correct hash-list?
Is there a way to obtain the reference to the hash-list-array, even if it's declared as static?

Or, maybe an uncommon idea: The hash-list is allocated via

```
pid_hash = alloc_large_system_hash("PID", sizeof(*pid_hash), 0, 18,HASH_EARLY | HASH_SMALL, &pidhash_shift, NULL,0, 4096);
```

So, if I could get the starting-position of the memory of the hash-list, could I scan the corresponding memoryspace for the pointer of my struct and then cast the surrounding memoryregion to struct of type **struct hlist**?

Thanks for your help. Every solution or idea is appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

There is a hash list available in sysmap file. you can check that once.

Answer (score 1):

The pid_hash can be located in /proc/kallsyms and also is accesible programatically by kallsyms_lookup_name.